# react-scripts start throws an error when webpack is installed to an existing react project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-scripts

I am getting an error in my react project after I run `npm start` after installing webpack.

```
npm install webpack
npm install webpack-dev-server
```

This is my package.json (without the above packages)

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.9.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

As soon as I install webpack and webpack-dev-server, I start getting this error on `npm start`

```
Failed to compile.

Error in   TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

  - ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:19 
    [myproject]/[webpack]/lib/ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:19:40

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:159 
    [myproject]/[react-scripts]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:159:3

  - Tapable.js:75 NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall
    [myproject]/[react-scripts]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:75:69

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:144 NormalModuleFactory.create
    [myproject]/[react-scripts]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:144:8

  - Compilation.js:356 Compilation.process [as _addModuleChain]
    [myproject]/[react-scripts]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:356:16

  - Compilation.js:424 Compilation.process [as addEntry]
    [myproject]/[react-scripts]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:424:7

  - SingleEntryPlugin.js:24 Compiler.<anonymous>
    [myproject]/[webpack]/lib/SingleEntryPlugin.js:24:16

  - Tapable.js:107 Compiler.applyPluginsParallel
    [myproject]/[react-scripts]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:107:14

  - Compiler.js:394 Compiler.compile
    [myproject]/[react-scripts]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:394:7

  - Compiler.js:203 Compiler.runAsChild
    [myproject]/[react-scripts]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:203:7

  - compiler.js:70 
    [myproject]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:70:19

  - compiler.js:69 Object.compileTemplate
    [myproject]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:69:10
```

Here is my npm version.

```
$ npm -v
4.5.0
```

Is this anything to do with my code or its an issue with the npm/react-scripts ?

Comment: If you're using `react-scripts`, why are you installing Webpack? `react-scripts` has Webpack built in - installing your own version over the top of it will probably not cause good things to happen.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that ... how to I build my code for production then ? can i do that with react-scripts ?

Comment: Yep - that's what `npm run build`/`react-scripts build` does. I'd really recommend reading [the documentation](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) - it'll cover all this :)

Comment: ok cool ... thanks mate